# How can I reference the parent of a prototype?

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript question so basic I can't even craft a proper Google query to answer it. By way of example:

```
function Parent(name){
  this.name = name;
}

Parent.prototype.Child() = function (){
  if(this.name == 'Sam'){ // This is the comparison that obviously doesn't work
    /* Do something */
  } else {
   /* Do something else */
  }
}

var Parent1 = new Parent('Sam');
var Child1 = new Parent1.Child();
```

Is there a keyword that could be used in place of the this in the comparison to access Parent's "name" property?

Cheers!

Comment: `Parent.prototype.Child() = function (){` should be `Parent.prototype.Child = function (){ `

Answer (score 1):

This example doesn't work because you've got `()` where it doesn't belong. It should look like  this:

```
Parent.prototype.Child = ...
```

Moreover, on this line..

```
var Child1 =  new Parent1.Child();
```

...it should be

```
var Child1 = Parent1.Child();
```

We took out the `new` because `Parent1` is not a constructor.

Your code will then behave as you expect.

Answer (score 1):

```
var Parent1= new Parent('sam')
```

this will create an object called parent1

since parent1 has the ability to use the child function

and it should be

```
Parent.prototype.Child = function (){
```

and finally you can use this

```
parent1.child()
```